# Visual Studio 2010 WebServer Very Slow loading

Tags: visual-studio-2010, webserver

I'm working on ASP.NET MVC2 project. 
everything was OK in the last months, today suddenly, the time to load the first page raised from 5 seconds to 1:30 min !

I check the output view and I see many lines like this one:

```
WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): 
Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.DurableInstancing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Runtime.DurableInstancing.dll', 
Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
```

some of them are totally irrelevant to my project like this one:

```
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): 
Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data.OracleClient\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.OracleClient.dll', 
Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
```

What happened ? I've tried to change in option not to load symbols, doesn't help, moved to release, same thing.

Any ideas what happened to my development environment ?
This is a Win7 X64 machine, VS2010 SP1.

Comment: Pause the debugger as it's frozen.   What is it doing?

Comment: I don't think it's the problem but have you enable source stepping or installed a tool like Reflector Addin? Also you can try disabling Intellitrace.

Comment: The Debugger is not running yet. it loads a lot of symbols, and only when it finishes with the symbols the debugger is on ("still attaching processes") I am not using Intellitrace.

Comment: I've checked on another computer, most of them are also loaded there, but at 1/100 of the time....

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Deleting all breakpoints solved this issue !

Comment: I started experiencing the exact same issue with Visual Studio 2010 while running a MVC3 project on local host with the Debugger.  All of my pages suddenly started taking at least 10x to load.  I found this question, and the six word answer.  Problem solved.  Thank you.

Comment: OMG!!.... I never thought a breakpoint could cause such harm....!!! I kept looking for a hole day... changing IPV6 to IPV4, disabling WCF services... omg... Simplicity always kills complexity...

Comment: Same issue with VS2012 / MVC4 / IIS Express (the message appearing started "'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)):").  I had just one breakpoint in Web.Release.Config and ended up with terrible slowdowns. I was running  a Debug build, so it's pretty odd a release transformation file was affecting it!